# DKIM settings in office 365

Tags: email, email-client, dkim

We have been told that our DKIM setting can be found on our mail server, unfortunately we use office 365, where can we find the settings for DKIM?  Are they even available in office 365?

Any advice on DKIM would be great as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is informative blog from Microsoft that indicates that DKIM is on Microsoft's roadmap for 2014.

http://blogs.office.com/2014/02/13/exchange-online-protection-enhancements-part-1/

Statement from the article is as follows:

Closer to the time of MEC 2014, when more new capabilities and enhancements are announced, we’ll introduce some of those new capabilities and enhancements in another blog post, Part 2, including:
•   End user access to quarantine
•   Enhanced support for IPV6
•   Domain Keys Identified Mail (DKIM)
•   Match subdomains

Dean Murray --
CloudStrategies.net

**UPDATE:**

As stated in the [recent blog post](http://blogs.office.com/2014/10/15/evolving-exchange-online-protection-eop-protect-tomorrows-threats/), DKIM will be probably implemented over the next six to twelve months.

Comment: 1 year later and it is "sort of" available: http://blogs.technet.com/b/eopfieldnotes/archive/2015/10/23/outbound-dkim-signing-in-office-365.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Inbound DKIM verification and filtering is partially supported (ipV6 only, v4 coming) with Office 365/Exchange Online per this MS Blog post:

http://blogs.office.com/2014/04/08/exchange-online-protection-enhancements-part-2/

Outbound signing still "coming".